# CodeIgniter Payments Getting a Success Response but not Working

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I'm using [CodeIgniter Payments](https://github.com/calvinfroedge/codeigniter-payments) to integrate with the Paypal API. I believe I am calling the right methods because I'm getting a response of "Success" but I don't see the transaction in the Sandbox. When I use the sample DoDirectPayment file from Paypal I complete the transaction and I can see it in the sandbox.

Here is my code using CodeIgniter Payments:

```
//load the payment library
$this->load->spark('codeigniter-payments/0.1.4/');

//configure the parameters for the payment request
$paymentParameters = array(
    'cc_type'       => 'foo',
    'cc_number'     => 'foo',
    'cc_exp'        => 'foo',
    'first_name'    => 'foo',
    'last_name'     => 'foo',
    'street'        => 'foo',
    'street2'       => 'foo',
    'city'          => 'foo',
    'state'         => 'foo',
    'country'       => 'foo',
    'postal_code'   => 'foo',
    'amt'           => 'foo',
    'currency_code' => 'USD'
);

//make the call
$paymentResponse = $this->payments->oneoff_payment('paypal_paymentspro', $paymentParameters);

//print the response
print_r($paymentResponse);
```

Here is the response:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [type] => gateway_response
    [status] => Success
    [response_code] => 100
    [response_message] => The authorization was successful.
    [details] => stdClass Object
    (
        [gateway_response] => stdClass Object
            (
                [TIMESTAMP] => 2012-05-22T19:18:17Z
                [CORRELATIONID] => 7939eeaa6c0c0
                [ACK] => Success
                [VERSION] => 66.0
                [BUILD] => 2929894
                [AMT] => 20.89
                [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
                [AVSCODE] => X
                [CVV2MATCH] => M
                [TRANSACTIONID] => 4RS01101TL8204042
            )

        [timestamp] => 2012-05-22T19:18:17Z
        [identifier] => 4RS01101TL8204042
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just switch into using other Paypal libraries. It might save you time than figuring out this problem. http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

In my case, I did not set my config driver correctly and it ended up sending all my transactions to Calvin's (Author's) default paypal sandbox account.

Double check to make sure that your API tokens are set correctly with:

```
$gateway_name = 'paypal_paymentspro';
$params = array(
    'identifier'    => *Your transaction ID from above* 
);
$response = $this->payments->get_transaction_details($gateway_name, $params);
print_r($results);
```

Also, if you don't want to set the driver and want to do everything from your PHP file, you can always pass in your API tokens like so:

```
$gateway_name = 'paypal_paymentspro';
$params = array(
    'identifier'    => *Your transaction ID from above* 
);
$config['api_username'] = *Your api username*;
$config['api_password'] = *Your api password*;
$config['api_signature'] = *Your sig*;
$response = $this->payments->get_transaction_details($gateway_name, $params);
print_r($results);
```